# Firebase Admin SDK GO VerifyIDToken returns not an App Engine context error

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-app-engine, go, firebase-authentication

I have a user authenticated with Firebase and what I want to do is to authenticate this user on the backend(Google cloud platform / Go) as well. I followed along with the document on [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens)

I get the idToken on the front end and send the token on the header to the server running on my localhost with the following code.

```
idToken = firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()
axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://localhost:8080/users',
    headers: {
      'Authentication-Token': idToken
    },
    data: {
        name: 'My name',
        user_name: 'my_user_name',
        email: 'example@example.com'
    }
})
```

On the backend I want to verify the idToken. I first create the auth client with the following code.

```
opt := option.WithCredentialsFile("firebase_credential.json")
app, err := firebase.NewApp(context.Background(), nil, opt)
client, err := app.Auth(context.Background())
```

With the client and the idToken from the frontend I tried the code below.

```
t, err := client.VerifyIDToken(context.Background(), idToken)
```

How ever this throws an error of

```
{"message":"Get https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com: oauth2: cannot fetch token: Post https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token: not an App Engine context"}
```

I also tried to `curl` the same request to the sever but the same error came out.

```
curl -X POST -H "Authentication-Token:hogehogemytoken" -d '{"name":"My name","user_name":"my user name","email":"example@example.com"}' http://localhost:8080/users
```

I am quite sure that I'm sending the right token.
Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe a bug of the library here? https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-go/issues/52

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in appengine Standard enviroment I had to use

```
ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)
```

rather than the

```
ctx := context.Background()
```

In an appengine request context, more complex things have to be handled since they are the API request context. On the other hand the general `context.Background()` is for general uses and therefore is not associated with incoming Http requests.

So my solution here was to pass the `appengine.NewContext(r)` in the init.go like below.

```
r.POST("/users", func(c *gin.Context) { up.CreateUser(c, appengine.NewContext(c.Request)) })
```

pass around this appengine context to the verify token.

```
func (c authClient) VerifyToken(ctx context.Context, token string) (IDToken, error) {
    opt := option.WithCredentialsFile("firebasecredential.json")
    app, err := firebase.NewApp(ctx, nil, opt)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    client, err := app.Auth(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    t, err := client.VerifyIDToken(ctx, token)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return idToken{t}, nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`VerifyIDToken` doesn't support context, check [documentation](https://godoc.org/firebase.google.com/go/auth#Client.VerifyIDToken)
as of now:

```
func (c *Client) VerifyIDToken(idToken string) (*Token, error)
```

The [link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-go/issues/52) in your comment points to the Future Request (FR), which means it's yet to be implemented, so it is not a bug.

You can use [`VerifyIDTokenAndCheckRevoked`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-go/tree/master/auth/auth.go#L257) does:

```
func (c *Client) VerifyIDTokenAndCheckRevoked(ctx context.Context, idToken string) (*Token, error)
```